# How to update the Grid which is in the repeater

Tags: gridview, repeater

I am having a Repeater which contains the Grid inside in it. Now if i click on Edit that is in the Grid that needs to show the edit item template that contains the Textboxes.

How can i achieve it?

Code:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptExpContent" runat="server" OnItemCommand="RptExpContent_OnItemCommand" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="outer">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <div class="innerTitle">
                                        <b>stagestepid:</b></div>
                                  <div class="innerContent">
                                        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "stepdesc")%>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgExpContent" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/toll_intweb_ico_plus.png"
                                            CommandName="Show" AlternateText="+" CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "stagestepid")%>'/>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="clear">
                                </div>
<asp:GridView ID="grdExpContent" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
                                OnRowCancelingEdit="GrdExpContent_RowCancelingEdit" DataKeyNames="stagestepfeeid,stagestepid,feetypeid">
                                <Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Stage Fee">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblFeeAlias" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("fee_alias") %>'>
                                            </asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFeeAlias" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("fee_alias")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```

Now i need to show the edit item template if i click on edit inside the Grid view that is in the Repeater.

This is very urgent,

Can i get a solution for this.

Thanks in Advance,
Prasad

Answer (score 0):

use the edit item template for the grid which is inside the repeater